# How may I extend (prolong or produce) a line segment accurately in the following geometrical figure?

Tags: tkz-euclide

[image]
The straight line `AP` must be extended until it meets the point `X` in `BC`. 
The extended line, `PX` must be a dashed line.

```
    \documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage{blindtext}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{tkz-euclide}
    \usetkzobj{all}
    \begin{document}
 \begin{center}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
 \tkzLabelPoints[xshift=-10pt](A)
 \tkzDefPoint(12,0){B}
 \tkzLabelPoints[xshift=-10pt](B)
 \tkzDrawSegment(A,B)
 \tkzDefPoint(7,8){C}
 \tkzLabelPoints[above](C)
 \tkzDrawSegment(A,C)
 \tkzDrawSegment(B,C)
 \tkzDefPoint(5,3){P}
 \tkzLabelPoints[above](P)
  \tkzDrawPoint[color=black,size=5 mm,fill=black](P)
  \tkzDrawSegment(A,P)
  \tkzDrawSegment(B,P)
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{center}
 \end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find `X` from the intersection of `AP` and `BC` using

```
\tkzInterLL(A,P)(B,C) \tkzGetPoint{X}
```

Then you can draw the line segment `PX` using

```
\tkzDrawSegment[dashed](P,X)
```

[image]

```
    \documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage{blindtext}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{tkz-euclide}
    \usetkzobj{all}
    \begin{document}
 \begin{center}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
 \tkzLabelPoints[xshift=-10pt](A)
 \tkzDefPoint(12,0){B}
 \tkzLabelPoints[xshift=-10pt](B)
 \tkzDrawSegment(A,B)
 \tkzDefPoint(7,8){C}
 \tkzLabelPoints[above](C)
 \tkzDrawSegment(A,C)
 \tkzDrawSegment(B,C)
 \tkzDefPoint(5,3){P}
 \tkzLabelPoints[above](P)
  \tkzDrawPoint[color=black,size=5 mm,fill=black](P)
  \tkzDrawSegment(A,P)
  \tkzDrawSegment(B,P)
\tkzInterLL(A,P)(B,C) \tkzGetPoint{X}
\tkzDrawSegment[dashed](P,X)
\tkzDrawPoint[color=black,size=5 mm,fill=black](X)
\tkzLabelPoints[above right](X)
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{center}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect set up! :)

Answer (score 1):

Rather straightforward with MetaPost, since it computes the intersection point implicitly thanks to the `whatever` variable. It is done by the instruction

```
X = whatever[A, P] = whatever[B, C];
```

This is a typical MetaPost instruction, and a very elegant one in my opinion.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
  \mplibsetformat{metafun} % provides the `enlarged` macro
  \mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{document}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
  u := cm;
  pair A, B, C, P, X; A = origin; B = u*(12, 0); C = u*(7, 8); P = u*(5, 3);
  X = whatever[A, P] = whatever[B, C]; % The intersection
  draw A--B--C--cycle; draw A--P--B; draw P--X dashed evenly;
  pickup pencircle scaled 3bp; drawdot P; drawdot X;
  label.bot("$A$", A); label.bot("$B$", B);
  label.top("$C$", C); label.top("$C$", C);
  label.top("$P$", P); label.urt("$X$", X);
  % Prevents label cropping by standalone
  setbounds currentpicture to bbox currentpicture enlarged 3bp; 
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

To be run with `LuaLaTeX`.

[image]

Comment: Never knew this before. This is VERY useful.